# How to set a newly created node's menu parent based on selected taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, routes

I am using the module taxonomy menu which autom. created menu items for each term of my vocabulary. Now, when I create a node and save it, I dont want the author to have to select the term AND set the menu parent to that exact term (twice) also.
Is there a way, for instance in the node presave hook, to look which term was selected and then set the created node's menu parent to that?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    function simplyvegan_node_presave($node) {
        if (isset($node->type) && $node->type == 'recipe') {
            if (isset($node->field_myvocabulary)) {
                $terms = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_myvocabulary');
                // debug($terms);
            // now set the node's menu parent to that term
        }
    }
}
```

**Update due to comment:**

I have radio buttons to select a term (= category of the node) when adding a node, for instance the vocab "categories" has the terms "awesome", "not so awesome" and "foobar". Everytime I add a term to that vocab, the above mentioned module automatically adds that term as a menu link.

So, instead of manually pick that term as the nodes parent menu item, I want my module to do that. In the menu settings, to the very bottom of the node creation form, you can check "add menu link" and choose what menu item will be the parent. Thats the thing.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by setting a menu parent to the exact term. I thinking parent of carrot being vegetable, not carrot itself.

Comment: More clear now?

Comment: Yes (after chatting too). You said in the chat that you're going for a different approach. Please update the question correspondingly.